# VBA Highlight cell if another cell is Highlighted

Tags: excel

Need a bit of help with some formatting. I'm thinking the only way to accomplish what I want is with vba formatting.

**Let me explain what the spreadsheet is doing first so you can understand:**

In cells B5:E5, user enters values based on different robot hand positions

Cell B5 is the first value entered and cells C5:E5 are compared to B5

Cell I5 calculates the total deviation of C5:E5 compared to B5

If total deviation is greater than 30, I5 turns red and in cells C5:E5, the lowest and highest values compared to B5 are highlighted yellow

In column R, the values entered in B5:E5 are converted by multiplying the values by 0.01 [this is how the values display on our GUI]

**Here is what I would like to do:**

If I5 is greater than 30, highest and lowest values in cells C5:E5 are highlighted yellow [this is already done]

What I would also like to do is highlight the corresponding values in column R

In the example below, since I5 is greater than 30, C5 and E5 are the highest and lowest values compared to B5 and are highlighted yellow.

How can I also highlight the values in R9 and R17 yellow to correlate with the highlighted values in C5 and E5?

Please keep in mind this should only happen if I5 is greater than 30.

[image]

Comment: Why not Conditional Formatting?

Comment: Do you need VBA? I think you can do it with conditional formatting only :)?

Comment: I have tried conditional formatting, but have been unsuccessful in applying a formula that would do what I am looking for. If you have suggestions for a conditional formula, please let me know and I will try them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this fulfill your criteria's.

I assume that the values in R column have the same logic as Range `C5:E5` i.e. the 61 will be the max value for both B5:E5 and R4:R17 (so R column couldn't have a value of 71 for example). I added a condition (`ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X Axis"`) to only apply if the Q column have the word "X Axis", since I think you might want to use another color/schema for Z Axis. Notice where `$` sign is used.

Max Value if Q column contains "X Axis". (Blue color):

```
=IF(AND($I$5>30,$I$5<>"",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X Axis",$Q4))),$R4=MIN($R$4:$R$18))
```

Min Value if Q column contains "X Axis". (Green color):

```
=IF(AND($I$5>30,$I$5<>"",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X Axis",$Q4))),$R4=MAX($R$4:$R$18))
```

[image]

Ranges I used are:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Wizhi! I had to modify your formula slightly to only look at specific cells instead of a range                           =IF(AND($I$5>30,$I$5<>""),$R9=MAX($R$9,$R$13,$R$17)) and =IF(AND($I$5>30,$I$5<>""),$R9=MIN($R$9,$R$13,$R$17))